# Calculating weighted marks within weighted marks

Tags: sql, math, azure-sql-database

I have a maths / SQL problem that I've been grappling with.

I have two tables with the following structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE Exams
(
ExamID INT PRIMARY KEY,
ExamName VARCHAR(100),
CourseID INT,
RelatedExamID INT NULL,
Weighting DECIMAL (5,3)
)

CREATE TABLE ExamMarks
(
ExamMarkID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
StudentID VARCHAR(8),
ExamID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Exams(ExamID),
ExamMark DECIMAL (5,4)
)
```

The exams table contains the following data:

```
INSERT INTO Exams (ExamID, ExamName, CourseID, RelatedExamID, Weighting)
VALUES (1, 'English',1,NULL,1),
(2, 'French',2,NULL,1),
(3, 'Maths',3,NULL,0.6),
(4, 'Statistics',3,NULL,0.4),
(5, 'Physics Part 1',4,NULL,0.5),
(6, 'Physics Part 2',4,NULL,0.5),
(7, 'Heat and Mass',4,6,0.25)
```

The Exam Marks table contains the following data:

```
INSERT INTO ExamMarks (StudentID, ExamID, ExamMark)
VALUES ('00112233', 1, 0.75),
('00112233', 2, 0.52),
('00112233', 3, 0.68),
('00112233', 4, 0.8),
('00112233', 5, 0.50),
('00112233', 6, 0.66),
('00112233', 7, 0.45)
```

The idea here is that a given course may have

- A single exam (such as with English and French)
- Multiple exams (such as with course 3, which has 2 exams called "Maths" and "Physics") which have independent weightings - in this case, the course is structured so that the Maths exam is 60% of the total, and the Physics exam contributes 40%
- Exams with sub-exams, such as with Course 4, more on which shortly.

If I want to get the weighted total marks for each candidate for each exam - forgetting about course 4 for the moment - I do the following:

```
SELECT em.StudentID,e.CourseID, SUM(em.ExamMark * e.Weighting)/SUM(e.Weighting)
FROM Exams e
INNER JOIN ExamMarks em ON e.ExamID = em.ExamID
GROUP BY em.StudentID,e.CourseID
```

However, Course 4 is made up of 3 parts:

- Physics Part 1 - 50% of the total, and
- Physics Part 2 - also 50% of the total
- Heat and Mass, which makes up 25% of Physics Part 2 (thus its ID in the 'RelatedExamID' column)

To be clear, Heat and Mass makes up 25% of Physics Part 2, which itself makes up 50% of the course.

I've put these figures into an Excel spreadsheet, and after a lot of head-scratching, was able to figure that our student should end up with a mark for Course 4 of 55.375%.

However, unfortunately, my SQL (and maths / logic) skills are not good enough to get to this result in a SQL query.

The data above represents something of a simplification. There are, in fact, around 10000 marks to be considered (around 500 students involved), for about 200 different exams, of which perhaps 30 are "sub-exams". Each year, these have to be totalled up to give the student their mark per course, given these weightings.

Comment: Can you include the formula to get the `55.375%` value?

Comment: Hmmm... The asterisks for multiplication are being interpreted as "convert to italics"! Is there a way of escaping these characters within comments? Let me try again:
```=(((PhysicsPart2Mark*(1-HeatAndMassWeighting))+(HeatAndMassMark*HeatAndMassWeighting))*PhysicsPart2Weighting)+(PhysicsPart1Mark*PhysicsPart1Weighting)```

Comment: OK. Since this makes up a tree of marks, this can be solved with a recursive CTE. Let me think about it. I assume there can be many nested levels.

Comment: What's the database? SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.

Comment: There would not be more than one level ever - it's just that one exam may have a coursework sub-component, which is recorded in this way (there's another column that I didn't mention called "component type" identifying it as exam or coursework). I am using SQL Azure. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have managed to find a solution. I'd still be grateful for any others which might be more efficient or robust from those who know more than me.

```
--Get SubComponent marks
WITH SubComponents
AS
(SELECT
        em.StudentID
       ,em.ExamID
       ,e.RelatedExamID
       ,e.Weighting
       ,e.Weighting * em.ExamMark AS WeightedMark
    FROM Exams e
    INNER JOIN ExamMarks em
        ON e.ExamID = em.ExamID
    WHERE e.RelatedExamID IS NOT NULL),
--Get marks for those components which have subcomponents
ParentComponents
AS
(SELECT
        em.StudentID
       ,e.CourseID
       ,em.ExamID
       ,e.RelatedExamID
       ,e.Weighting
       ,((1 - SubComponents.Weighting) * em.ExamMark) 
            + SubComponents.WeightedMark AS OverallComponentMark
    FROM Exams e
    INNER JOIN ExamMarks em
        ON e.ExamID = em.ExamID
    INNER JOIN SubComponents
        ON SubComponents.RelatedExamID = e.ExamID
        AND SubComponents.StudentID=em.StudentID),

--Get marks for those components which are neither parent nor child components
StandaloneComponents
AS
(SELECT
        em.StudentID
       ,e2.CourseID
       ,em.ExamID
       ,e2.RelatedExamID
       ,e2.Weighting
       ,em.ExamMark
    FROM Exams e2
    INNER JOIN ExamMarks em
        ON e2.ExamID = em.ExamID
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
            *
        FROM Exams
        WHERE RelatedExamID = e2.ExamID)
    AND e2.RelatedExamID IS NULL),

-- Bring all the above together
ComponentMarks
AS
(SELECT
        StudentID
       ,CourseID
       ,ExamID
       ,Weighting
       ,ExamMark
    FROM StandaloneComponents
    UNION
    SELECT
        StudentID
       ,CourseID
       ,ExamID
       ,Weighting
       ,OverallComponentMark
    FROM ParentComponents)

-- Finally group and combine marks at course level
SELECT
    StudentID
   ,CourseID
   ,SUM(ExamMark * Weighting) / SUM(Weighting)
FROM ComponentMarks
GROUP BY StudentID
        ,CourseID
```